# Deploying Rails with Elastic Beanstalk 404 Not Found Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my Ruby on Rails app with Elastic Beanstalk. I was following this guide - http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx2AK2MFX0QHRIO/Deploying-Ruby-Applications-to-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk-with-Git

But unfortunately, when I go to the site it shows

404 Not Found
nginx/1.4.3

eb status --verbose gives this:

```
Retrieving status of environment "SurveyMe".
URL             : SurveyMe-i5dkejjacp.elasticbeanstalk.com
Status          : Ready
Health          : Green
Environment Name: SurveyMe
Environment ID  : e-rtzrvemw53
Environment Tier: WebServer::Standard::1.0
Solution Stack  : 64bit Amazon Linux 2013.09 running Ruby 1.9.3
Version Label   : git-b2f153a095a4392b2c77a9e40a3bd91acf02757e-1391723347993
Date Created    : 2014-02-06 21:36:28
Date Updated    : 2014-02-06 21:49:37
Description     :
```

I saw a few questions with a similar problem but most had errors here. Any ideas what might be going on or what to check? The app is currently deployed with Heroku - could that be an issue?

Including my routes.rb

```
SurveyMe::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :developers
  devise_for :users
  mount Rapidfire::Engine => "/surveys"
  root :to => "static_pages#home"
  match "/about", to: "static_pages#use", via: "get"
  match "/developers", to: "static_pages#developer" , via: "get"
  match "/how", to: "static_pages#how", via: "get"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's Rails application. Check your routes under:

```
<your app dir>/config/routes.rb
```

You should have something defined for the root route:

```
# Application home
root :to => 'welcome#index'
```

Comment: Same issue unfortunately. I added my routes.rb file above - previously the line was just root "static_pages#home", but I updated it with your recommendation.